# Note on 1549 Narrenschiff woodcut

Tags: translation

What is the writing on this woodcut? *Nul on Urlaub* doesn't seem to make sense, aber mein Deutsch is sehr schlecht.

[image]

Comment: It it helps, the full title page is on [Wikimedia commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Narrenschiff_Titelblatt.jpg).

Comment: To add to @HalvarF 's answer, the `ſ` is not a lowercase "L", it's a "[langes s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur#/media/File:Fraktur_letter_S.png)" in [Frakturschrift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

"Nüt on Ursach" (Nichts [ist] ohne Ursache. Nothing [happens] without a reason/cause.)

It's a motto from the popular book ["Das Narrenschiff"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_Narrenschiff_(Brant)) (ship of fools) by Sebastian Brant that was first published in 1494.

Prints of the book [from 1506](https://archive.org/details/DoctorBrantsNarrensciff1506/page/n9/mode/2up) [and 1512](https://archive.org/details/DoctorBrantsNarrensciff1512/page/n5/mode/2up) show the motto  prominently on the title page. The original print from 1494 does not have the motto on the title page, but only [in the editor's sign](https://digital.slub-dresden.de/werkansicht/dlf/11823/318) by [Johann Bergmann von Olpe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Bergmann_von_Olpe), who also used it in his sign on other works he edited (sometimes in Latin as *nihil sine causa*). So I'm not sure about the original relation between the motto and Brant's text.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the idea is older: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Nothing_comes_from_nothing

Comment: ooh, what a wonderful motto! Vielen dank! Aber warum ist es "Ursach" (cause?) und nicht "Grund" (reason)? is that just a well-known idiom?

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the language is not Modern German, but Early New High German which is substantially different, just at Shakespeare's English was different from Modern English. @Jason S: I know you mean well, but it's kind of bad form to use Denglisch here. It's language you'd associate with advertising and pop songs, so not really suitable for the general tone used on the site. (Heidi Bachert's rendition of "My Boy Lollipop" comes to mind.)

Comment: @RDBury On the contrary: I think Jason S does not yet speak German well enough to write entirely in that language but tries to insert fragments in German out of good will and politeness. The comparison with a Germanophone  pop-singer who for some reason mixes German and English is, in my opinion, completely inappropriate.

Comment: @JasonS Grund und Ursache sind in der Bedeutung sehr ähnlich, teils synonym.

Comment: @JasonS If understand the (very long) entry in Grimm's "Deutsches Wörterbuch" correctly, it took until the 18th century for the use of "Grund" in the sense of "Ursache" to become widespread.

Comment: @RDBury ok I will just use English then, if that's permitted on this site.

Comment: ...so in English "reason" and "cause" are very similar, but part of the difference is that a reason for something involves intent or meaning, whereas cause just happens. Was the word "Ursach" used in both cases?

Comment: @HalvarF -- interesting links -- the printer played fast and loose with "u" and "v" letters -- https://archive.org/details/DoctorBrantsNarrensciff1506/page/n17/mode/2up -- "vnd" / "vrsach" / "Uon" / "Uerstand" -- also the two forms of "r": "vorlich" looks like "vozlich"